# how to get the source code as register user

Tags: c#

i downloaded a sourcecode of a site,but i downloaded it i saw it identify my program as a guest,i search at google and figure out that i can send a cookie when i "ask" the source code.
that what i have managed to do and it still dont identify me as register user:

```
CookieContainer cj = new CookieContainer();
string all = "";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.CookieContainer = cj;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
CookieCollection cs=cj.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
cc.Add(cs);
req.CookieContainer = cc;
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
all = read.ReadToEnd();
read.Close();             
return all;
```

what is wrong here?
tyvm for help:)
(if that help,i can have a simple details of a register user of the site).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: "ask" the source code - do you just mean request/response?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the cookie that the server left behind in your cookie cache that identified you as a authenticated user in a previous session.  You'll need to use the Cookie(name, value) constructor.  Getting the value is the tricky part, look through your cookie cache to see if you can find one.  It is still going to fail if the server expires the cookie.

Using a tool that lets you look at the HTTP headers and cookie values is important to debug this.  Firebug is very nice.

Comment: ty for answer.
i downloaded cookie editor add on in google chrome and as i see there is like 5-6 values named as: PHPSESSID and _utma and others which name to write? and there is a way to get the value from the c# program and not manually? ty

Comment: I don't know.  Contact the web site owner for support.